# jQuery how to target the label in my example

Tags: jquery, text, label

Having a strangely tough time trying to target and change the text of my label

```
<li>
    <label></label><br/>
    <input type='tel' class='added_phone' name='' value='' maxlength='20' />
</li>
```

My Variable:

```
// Phone Inputs
var inputphone = $("<li><label></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");
```

The function with checks how many Phone objects exist and then create them on the page:

```
$(profileData.phones).each(function(i) {
    $('.new_option').append(inputphone);
    $('.added_phone').closest('label').text(profileData.phones[0].tag);
    $('.added_phone').attr('id', "added_"+profileData.phones[0].tag+"phone" + (i + 1));
        });
    $('.added_phone').attr('value', profileData.phones[0].label);
});
```

[image]

I'm able to find out that there is 1 or more phone objects, create and display the input, put the phone number into the field, but have not been able to target the label and put in the tag(name).

Tried closest, parent, label... code tunnel X_x

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, given your following HTML:

```
<li>
    <label></label><br/>
    <input type='tel' class='added_phone' name='' value='' maxlength='20' />
</li>
```

Then, from the `input`, the `label` is:

```
$(this).parent().find('label');
```

Or:

```
$(this).prevAll('label');
```

Note that both these methods will potentially return multiple elements, should any `li` contain more than one `label`/`input`.

Incidentally, you're using the `label` wrong; it's *meant* to identify a relationship a text-label and a `form`'s `input` (or `textarea` or `select`) elements:

> This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.

Taking advantage of the `for` attribute of the `label` which must (if it's to work) be the same as the `id` attribute of the `input` (or similar element):

```
<li>
    <label for="inputID"></label><br/>
    <input id="inputID" type='tel' class='added_phone' name='' value='' maxlength='20' />
</li>
```

And, given that relationship, it becomes somewhat easier to associate the two (assuming that `this` refers to the `input` element):

```
$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`for` attribute reference, W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-for).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and clear explanation regarding use of the `<label>` element. Well done +1.

Comment: Thanks! This was a tough choice, both answers are perfect, thanks for the references :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .parent() and .find() selectors to locate the desired element:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9HX99/)

HTML:

```
<div class="new_option"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var inputphone = $("<li id='myLI'><label id='myLabel'></label><br/><input type='tel' class='added_phone' /></li>");
    $('.new_option').append(inputphone);
    alert($('.added_phone').parent().find('label').attr('id'));
});
```

And to update your label field itself:

[updated jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9HX99/1/)

```
$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var inputphone = $("<li id='myLI'><label id='myLabel'></label><br/><input type='tel' class='added_phone' /></li>");
    $('.new_option').append(inputphone);
    //alert($('.added_phone').parent().find('label').attr('id'));
    $('.added_phone').parent().find('label').text('Hey there');
});
```

Comment: Thanks +1 and taking the time for the jsFiddle!